# Changing comparator in WHERE clause has catastrophic results on query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a monster query that I'm running against a SQL SERVER 2005 database that is acting very strange.  I have two conditions in the WHERE clause of the outermost select, comparing a field to a constant date.  When the constant dates are either identical (down to the second) or their date parts are not equal, the query runs in under 2 seconds.  When the date parts are the same but the time parts are different, the query takes around 7 minutes to complete.  Specifically, having a WHERE clause of

```
WHERE
  d.date >= '2011-11-07 00:00:00' AND
  d.date <= '2011-11-08 11:59:59'
```

works well and as expected.  Changing the WHERE clause to

```
WHERE
  d.date >= '2011-11-07 00:00:00' AND
  d.date <= '2011-11-07 11:59:59'
```

causes the query to take many minutes.

I also noticed that when I turned off the index on the Agent_Hours table that the bad case of having the same dates the same reduces the query time to 25 seconds, still far longer than when they dates are different, but not by as much.

Below is the full query for reference (the WHERE clause in question is at the very end):

```
SELECT
  s.transaction_id AS 'transaction',
  s.created_on AS transaction_date,
  s.first_name + ' ' + s.Last_Name AS customer_name,
  a.name AS agent_name,
  a.phantom AS phantom,
  a.team AS agent_team,
  a.id AS agent_number,
  h.hours,
  h2.hours_today,
  d.*
FROM
  (SELECT
     agents.first_name + ' ' + agents.last_name AS name,
     agents.id AS id,
     agents.phantom AS phantom,
     transient.value AS team,
     transient.start_date AS team_start_date,
     transient.end_date AS team_end_date
   FROM
       Agents.dbo.Agent_Static AS agents
     JOIN
       Agents.dbo.Agent_Transient AS transient
     ON transient.agent = agents.id
   WHERE
     transient.field = 'team') AS a
  LEFT JOIN Agents.dbo.Agent_Daily AS d
    ON d.agent = a.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               agent_hours.agent AS agent,
               dates.date AS date,
               CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / 4 AS hours
             FROM
                 Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours AS agent_hours
               JOIN
                 (SELECT
                    DISTINCT CONVERT(
                               VARCHAR(10),
                               hour_worked,
                               101)
                               AS date
                  FROM
                    Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours) AS dates
               ON dates.date = CONVERT(
                                 VARCHAR(10),
                                 agent_hours.hour_worked,
                                 101)
             WHERE
               (status = 'Phone' OR
                status = 'Meeting')
             GROUP BY
               agent_hours.agent,
               dates.date) AS h
    ON h.agent = a.id AND
       h.date = d.date
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               agent_hours.agent AS agent,
               dates.date AS date,
               CAST(COUNT(*) AS FLOAT) / 4 AS hours_today
             FROM
                 Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours AS agent_hours
               JOIN
                 (SELECT
                    DISTINCT CONVERT(
                               VARCHAR(10),
                               hour_worked,
                               101)
                               AS date
                  FROM
                    Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours) AS dates
               ON dates.date = CONVERT(
                                 VARCHAR(10),
                                 agent_hours.hour_worked,
                                 101)
             WHERE
               (status = 'Phone' OR
                status = 'Meeting') AND
               CONVERT(
                 VARCHAR(10),
                 CAST('11/09/2011 13:01' AS DATETIME),
                 101) = CONVERT(
                          VARCHAR(10),
                          agent_hours.hour_worked,
                          101) AND
               CONVERT(
                 VARCHAR(10),
                 CAST('11/09/2011 13:01' AS DATETIME),
                 114) > CONVERT(
                          VARCHAR(10),
                          agent_hours.hour_worked,
                          114)
             GROUP BY
               agent_hours.agent,
               dates.date) AS h2
    ON h2.agent = a.id AND
       h2.date = d.date
  LEFT JOIN sale_transactions AS s
    ON a.id = s.agent_hermes_id AND
       s.created_on >= a.team_start_date AND
       s.created_on <= a.team_end_date AND
       CONVERT(
         VARCHAR(10),
         d.date,
         101) = CONVERT(
                  VARCHAR(10),
                  s.created_on,
                  101)
  LEFT JOIN sold_phrases AS p
    ON s.Transaction_ID = p.transaction_id
WHERE
  d.date >= '2011-11-07 00:00:00' AND
  d.date <= '2011-11-07 11:59:59'
```

Comment: I can not find any differences in WHERE clauses you've provided

Comment: Same, but if you look at the end of his entire query, the `WHERE` clause is different from the two on top: `WHERE 
  d.date >= '2011-11-07 00:00:00' AND 
  d.date <= '2011-11-07 11:59:59'`. He also mentions having a `WHERE` with "the same date" in the question body, so this is probably the difference.

Comment: Right but considering such confused thing it does not make sense reviewing question further since this could be a guesswork nothing more, it worst when question contains such errors

Comment: My apologies, there was a typo in the second WHERE clause example.  I've updated the question to correct it.

Comment: Lots of CASTing and CONVERTing going on; instead of doing string comparisons, you may be able to pick up some performance by using date conversion functions.

Comment: Stuart, if you could point in the the right direction there it'd be most appreciated.  All my googling led me to believe that the CONVERTs are the best way to compare just the date or time parts of a DateTime field, but if there is a better way, I would be quite interested in learning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, always post your exact table definition, including all indexes, when asking performance problems in SQL.

I cannot see any difference between the two cases, but considering your explanation, this is what likely happens: the cardinality estimates for the date range may trigger the [index tipping point](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx) and you get  wildly different execution plans. Such issues are best addressed by using plan guides, see [Optimizing Queries in Deployed Applications by Using Plan Guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187032.aspx). You should be able to confirm if the problem is indeed the plan, see [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071.aspx).

Comment: Indeed the execution plans are different between the two cases.  Reading through your links, am I to gather that what's happening here is that SQL Server is guessing that it'd be quicker to do the query one way when the dates are the same, and ultimately being very very wrong?  If that's the case, is there a way to trick it into always using the faster option that it uses when the dates the different?

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe a micro optimization but have you consider changing the way you get the date part from `datetime` to `DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, datetime_format))`. It's usually faster way than `convert` function.

```
SELECT
  s.transaction_id AS 'transaction',
  s.created_on AS transaction_date,
  s.first_name + ' ' + s.Last_Name AS customer_name,
  a.name AS agent_name,
  a.phantom AS phantom,
  a.team AS agent_team,
  a.id AS agent_number,
  h.hours,
  h2.hours_today,
  d.*
FROM (SELECT
     agents.first_name + ' ' + agents.last_name AS name,
     agents.id AS id,
     agents.phantom AS phantom,
     transient.value AS team,
     transient.start_date AS team_start_date,
     transient.end_date AS team_end_date
   FROM
       Agents.dbo.Agent_Static AS agents
     JOIN
       Agents.dbo.Agent_Transient AS transient
     ON transient.agent = agents.id
   WHERE
     transient.field = 'team'
) AS a
LEFT JOIN Agents.dbo.Agent_Daily AS d ON d.agent = a.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        agent_hours.agent AS agent, 
        dates.date AS date,
        COUNT(*) / 4.0 AS hours
    FROM Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours AS agent_hours
    JOIN (
        SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, hour_worked)) as date
        FROM Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, hour_worked))
    ) AS dates ON dates.date = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, agent_hours.hour_worked))
    WHERE (status = 'Phone' OR status = 'Meeting')
    GROUP BY agent_hours.agent, dates.date
) AS h ON h.agent = a.id AND h.date = d.date
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        agent_hours.agent AS agent,
        dates.date AS date, 
        COUNT(*) / 4.0 AS hours_today
    FROM Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours AS agent_hours
    JOIN (
        SELECT DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, hour_worked)) as date
    FROM Agents.dbo.Agent_Hours GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, hour_worked))
    ) AS dates ON dates.date = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, agent_hours.hour_worked))
    WHERE 
        (status = 'Phone' OR status = 'Meeting') AND
        agent_hours.hour_worked >=
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, CAST('11/09/2011 13:01' AS DATETIME)))
        AND
        agent_hours.hour_worked <
        CAST('11/09/2011 13:01' AS DATETIME)
    GROUP BY agent_hours.agent, dates.date
    ) AS h2 ON h2.agent = a.id AND h2.date = d.date

  LEFT JOIN sale_transactions AS s
    ON a.id = s.agent_hermes_id AND
       s.created_on >= a.team_start_date AND
       s.created_on <= a.team_end_date AND
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, d.date))
        = 
        DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, s.created_on))
  LEFT JOIN sold_phrases AS p
    ON s.Transaction_ID = p.transaction_id
WHERE
  d.date >= '2011-11-07 00:00:00' AND
  d.date <= '2011-11-07 11:59:59'
```

The more important (as Remus Rusanu already wrote) are indexes. Execute both queries and check which indexes are used in faster query and force SQL Server to use them always. You can do it using [`with(index(index_name))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx).